# Error getting value in PointerByReference with JNA and Delphi DLL

Tags: java, delphi, dll, jna

I need to develop a Java program with a Delphi DLL, but a problem is:

I mapped in JNA as follows:

**- Delphi function:**

```
function send_command (const command : byte; var size : byte; var data : pbyte) : integer; stdcall external 'comunication.dll';
```

**- Java function:**

```
public int send_command(byte command, ByteByReference size, PointerByReference data);
```

The function returned 1 (Success result) but I can´t get the value in **data** variable.

How can I get the value in **data** ?

In **Delphi Test Program**, the function is called as follows:

```
const
    cmdREAD_STATUS = $17;

procedure TForm1.ReadStatus1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    Data,
    p    : pbyte;
    tam  : byte;
    i,
    result: integer;
    saux : string;
begin
    getmem (Data, 40);
    tam:= 0;
    result:= send_comand (cmdREAD_STATUS, tam, Data);
    if result= 1 then
      begin
        memo1.Lines.add ('Command OK');
        i:= 0;
        sAux:= '';
        p:= Data;
        while (i < Tam) do
          begin
            sAux:= sAux + inttohex (p^, 2)+' ';
            if length (sAux) > 59 then
              begin
                memo1.Lines.add (SAux);
                sAux:= '';
              end;
            inc (p);
            inc (i);
          end;
        if sAux <> '' then
          memo1.Lines.add (SAux);
      end
    else
      memo1.Lines.add ('Result: '+inttostr(result)+' in command execution');
    freemem (Data);
end;
```

Comment: what do you mean by "can´t get the value in data variable"?

Comment: This DLL speaks with an equipment and this function return a array of bytes, in Delphi returns as the example of test software.

Comment: I'd still recommend fixing the delphi code

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, changing the variables ? byte to BYTE and pbyte to PBYTE ?

Comment: What code is not working exactly?  The Delphi code that populates `data`, or the Java code that tried to read from `data`?  You need to be more specific.

Comment: No. Removing the var from the data argument.

Comment: Only remove var, not add const ? Sorry, I know nothing of Delphi.

Comment: If the callee is allocating memory and "returning" a pointer (as appears to be the case), you can extract the pointer with `PointerByReference.getValue()`.  If the caller is providing a buffer, then `Memory` or `byte[]` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it using the [`Memory`](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Memory.html) class.

```
Memory memory = new Memory(40);
PointerByReference data = new PointerByReference();
data.setValue(memory);
// call the function now
byte[] bytes = new byte[40];
memory.read(0, bytes, 0, 40);
```

Bear in mind that I don't know Java at all and so there may well be syntax errors in the above. But I'm confident that the basic approach is sound.

Comment: I used this example but the JVM is stoping to work in the final of execution.

Comment: I suggest you try some debugging then. Do you understand what the code does?

Comment: Ok. I will try to debug. Yes ... Allocate in memory (40 positions) like in Delphi Teste Program. Even then it´s necessary change the DLL ( remove var ) ?

Comment: So I'd start by making a Delphi DLL with a function having the same prototype. Then arrange that the function simply writes its inputs to the console. Call it from a Java console app. Prove that the interop works first before you try to use the real DLL.

Comment: The big problem is that the DLL is provided by another company working for this my client, but I´ll try.

Comment: The reason I suggest making you own test dll is to be sure that the interop works, or doesn't.

Comment: Yes. I´ll try with C++ DLL. Thank you one more time @DavidHeffernan

Comment: In C++ the signature is `int __stdcall send_command(unsigned char command, unsigned char *size, unsigned char **data);`

Comment: I think you'd want `data.setValue(memory)`, so that you're passing an "address" of the pointer to allocated memory.  `data.setValue(memory.getPointer(0))` extracts a pointer from uninitialized memory.  You can also initialize any `XXXByReference` by passing the desired value into the constructor.

Comment: @technomage that won't compile though because `setValue` expects `Pointer`. Pointer to uninitialized memory is exactly what is wanted. The native code populates it. The Delphi programmer made a mistake by making `Data` be a var parameter, hence the unusual extra level of indirection.

Comment: `Memory` derives from `Pointer`.  `memory.getPointer(0)` doesn't give you a pointer to uninitialized memory (that's what `memory` is), it reads a pointer value from uninitialized memory, which will likely be `null`.

Comment: @technomage Ok. I see. I'll update. Thank you. If you'd like to write a better answer I'll gladly yield to your knowledge of the java side.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thanks David Heffernan and technomage.